# Castle ActiveRecord and HQL - problem with retrieveing data from table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql, castle-activerecord

I'm using Castle ActiveRecord for my project on C# and I have a weird error. I want to retrieve data from one specified column via ActiveRecord methods, so that I could put it into comboBox.

I use this method with simple query:

```
...
using Castle.ActiveRecord.Queries;
...
public static Lable[] ReturnAllLableNames()
    {
        SimpleQuery<Lable> q = new SimpleQuery<Lable>(typeof(Lable), @"
        Select LableName
        from Lable 
        ");
        return q.Execute();
    }
```

where Lable is a table and also a class in my project, which has LableID and LableName columns.

The first time I built and tried to run my project, VS asked me to specify the ActiveRecordBaseQuery.cs file, which of course I didn't have, so I pressed "Cancel" and rebuilt my project. The next time I had a following error:

```
Could not perform ExecuteQuery for Lable
```

[error details](http://pastebin.com/rLEXuKVN)

[my class](http://pastebin.com/Ubk8ZkM2)

I have no clues where I should search for my error, because I used this code from SimpleQuery examples and I added all necessary references to my class.

On the second thought, is there any other way to retrieve one specified column using Castle AR methods?

I'd be happy to hear any clues regarding my problem.

Comment: I made a temporary solution for now. Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/7zdTAQrv (maybe someone would find it useful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate's HQL, unlike SQL, [is case sensitive for properties and class names](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-casesensitivity). In your case, the property is called `labelName`, not `LabelName` as it says in the query. I recommend changing the property name to `LabelName` (see [.net design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx)).

Also, if you're using C# 3.0+ you might want to use [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

Also, IIRC you need to use fully-qualified properties in the query, e.g. `select l.LabelName from Label l`

Finally, if you mean to return a list of strings (`LabelName`s), you need to change the signature of the method and also use `SimpleQuery<string>` instead of `SimpleQuery<Label>`. See the [SimpleQuery docs](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/hql.html#SimpleQuery) for reference.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know where I should start searching for my error. However the change of letter case didn't solve the problem, it's probably somewhere in HQL.